# How to parse content easily?

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, urllib

I am learning the Urllib functions. The parsing code I have wrote is not selecting all of the information off the webpage.

I have changed the User Agent header so the request shows as a real user. Some of the information is showing off the page but mostly the small print.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

print('Webpage content surfer')

try:
    url = input('Enter full website address (http://, https://:> ')
    headers = {}
    headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (x11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17'
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    respdata = resp.read()


except Exception as e:
    print('That is not a valid website address\nCheck the web address'
          , (e))

content = re.findall(r'<p>(.*?)</p>', str(respdata))
for contents in content:
    print(contents)
```

I am not showing any errors but the content is not displaying all the content on the page. Is this due to requesting all of the information between paragraphs using

()

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested you code against http://example.com and it seems to display all contents between `<p> .. </p>`
Is there a particular URL you are having issues with?
I also suggest you use [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/)

Comment: I have inspected the elements on pages like Google search results. It is showing that there is a Parse blocker active on it. Nearly every https:// site I inspect the elements on shows a Parse blocker.

Comment: Parse blocker means the websites you are trying to scape are Javascript heavy. You might want to look into Web-scraping using selenium.
https://stanford.edu/~mgorkove/cgi-bin/rpython_tutorials/Scraping_a_Webpage_Rendered_by_Javascript_Using_Python.php

Comment: Thanks for the info! Selenium does the job